# Call class method from inside of same class instance in C#

Tags: c#, static

```cs
public class MyClass {
  public static int SomeMethod(string param){
    return .....;
  }

  public int SomeMethod(string param){
    return MyClass.SomeMethod(param);
  }
}
```

Here when I rename class, I should rename it in all the static method calls.

In Ruby I am able to do following:

```rb
class MyClass
  def self.some_method(param)
    #.....
  end

  def some_method(param)
    self.class.some_method(param)
  end
end
```

How to do the same in C# ?

Comment: You can't even write that code in C# - you've got two methods with the same signature in the same class.

Comment: Note that you really don't need to specify `MyClass.` for calling static method of the same class (assuming "method with the same signature already exists" issue pointed out by Jon Skeet present because it is sample).

Comment: Yeah, it seems that in C# there is enough to have only one (static) method and it can be called from instance without specifying class name.

Answer (score 3):

C# doesn't have similar syntax, so you should rename all the method calls.